# urlrewritingnet - rewrite="Domain" not working

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, umbraco

I'm trying to rewrite a path on an Umbraco website to load a sub-domain - is this possible? Using the config setting below I'm getting the Exception message: 'http://subdomain.domain.com' is not a valid virtual path.

```
    <add name="compare"  virtualUrl="http://www.domain.com/directory/?$"
     rewrite="Domain" destinationUrl="http://subdomain.domain.com" 
   ignoreCase="true"  />
```

Has anybody successfully used rewrite="Domain"? All of the examples that I've seen use redirect="Domain".

Answer (score 1):

I have used this on several sites to redirect to www.domain.com when I don't have access to IIS.

```
 <add name="SEOfix"  virtualUrl="^http\://domain.com/(.*)"
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
    destinationUrl="http://www.domain.com/$1"
    redirect="Domain"
    redirectMode="Permanent"
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Is that what you're trying to do?